# Put Mobile App Launch Icon on Notifications Screen to Launch from Locked Device

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins

Want to put the icon for our iOS app on the iOS Notifications Screen that can be accessed when a user has not entered their passcode, so that the user can launch the app when the phone is locked without needing to input their passcode.  The goal is for a very fast launch with minimum time from a locked iphone.  We don't need to actually send the user a notification.  Would also be great for this to work on Android, but iOS is currently more important for this feature.

What is the best way to do this using Cordova?  Is there an existing plugin for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible to launch your app without unlocking the phone

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to launch an iOS app without unlocking the phone/device.  The notifications screen is only available once the iOS device is unlocked.

(thanks to dan)